# What is a concise way to restate this phrase?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, concision

Recently, I have been stuck on how to make a certain phrase more concise. I am unsure if there is some word, or particular phrase that will shorten the following:

> "desire for dreams to become reality"

In other terms, I am wondering if there is a more concise way to put this, and if there is a single word that describes exactly what is to be conveyed in this phrase.

Comment: Please provide a sentence or sentences showing how you would use the phrase or word you're searching for.

Comment: Sounds like *hope*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could say that the person *hopes to*, wishes to, wants to, or works to **realize** his or her dreams*, using the following definition of the word [***realize***:](http://www.wordnik.com/words/realize)

> ***realize:*** To make real; to convert from the imaginary or fictitious into the actual; to bring into concrete existence; to effectuate; to accomplish.

The word *realize* doesn't encapsulate the "desire" part of your phrase, so you would still need a word or two to capture that aspect.

---

**Borrowing from @Kevin's comment*